# Filling out an affidavit of personal service

Tags: new-york-state, process

I am filling out an affidavit of personal service, "Form D," found at http://www.sro.nysed.gov/forms/default.html

For the most part, the fill-in-the-blanks parts look pretty straightforward.  The top part of the page is where I'm unsure.  Where it says "County of" -- I can do that.  Is there anything else to be filled out in that top area?  For example, "ss.:"?

Question also about the part that says, "by delivering to and leaving with said __________________________ (receiver of papers)": Do I write in the name of the employee (person) served?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you write in the name of the person actually served.

Keep in mind that a party to an action (e.g. the Plaintiff) is not allowed to serve process in that case. It must be served by a person eighteen or older who is not a party and is not an attorney in the case. It sounds as if you might be serving process in a case in which you are the Plaintiff and if so, that is not O.K., you need to find a friend, or hire a "process server" or a sheriff's deputy to deliver the papers. And, the person who serves the papers, rather than the party, must sign the affidavit before a notary.

The language "ss." is a Latin abbreviation stands for “scilicet” which means "in particular" or "namely" and simply indicates where the venue information on a certificate is located. For your purposes it means, this affidavit was signed in the state and county immediately preceding this abbreviation and requires no further elaboration.

Comment: Thanks but I knew about the 18 or older uninvolved person. // I am taking your answer to mean that the only thing I need write in the top portion of the page is the name of the county.

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm saying.